# Java : Convert Color string value to Hexa value

Tags: java, string, colors, hex

I am trying to change color value to color `hexa` code. So, I code like this:

```
color = Integer.toHexString(colorpick.getValue().hashCode()).substring(0, 6).toUpperCase();
```

The above code is **Ok** for all colors except for **"Black"** color.

It gives the following error for **"Black"** color.

```
String index out of range : 6 error
```

Is any solution for my problem, please?

Comment: Okay, cool story, although the character development was lacking. Did you have a question?

Comment: Ask clearly!!! I think that you mean, you code give error for input value "Black". Is Right?

Comment: Check the return value of **`colorpick.getValue()`**. I think, the problem come from that part.

Comment: Yes, my question is why does it work for every color except the black

Answer (score 2):

this is absolutely wrong here:

```
colorpick.getValue().hashCode()
```

hashcode is a specific code generated by the JVM to manage hash numbers related to instances and hash-tables... and has NOTHING to do with colors..

this should be more than ok

```
colorpick.getValue()
```

Comment: When I run the code `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Color.BLACK.hashCode()));`, It give me result **`ff000000`**. So, I think that the problem is not from `hashCode()`.

Comment: And **hashCode** method for color is from **`int java.awt.Color.hashCode()`**. So, It is related for use.

Comment: I get this error when i remove the substring,                              The method toHexString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Color)

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not mention what class the variable "colorpick" is, I'm going to assume it's ColorPicker (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ColorPicker.html).

I don't think its hashcode() method is overriden to return the RGB value in hex.

The cause of your error is that black's RGB value is 0. Applying .toHexString() will only give you "0", a single character, hence the .substring() will not work. Other RGB values may also result in a string shorter than 6.

I assume you want the result to be always 6-digit; then you should pad the string with 0 from the start if it's shorter.

**Edit** 
ColorPicker.getValue() returns a Color object, not the RGB value.
So you should use colorpick.getValue().getRGB() instead.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB()

**Edit2**
With and without .getRGB():

```
Color c = Color.CYAN;
String s = Integer.toHexString(c.getRGB() & 0xFFFFFF).toUpperCase();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 6 - s.length(); i++) {
    sb.append("0");
}
sb.append(s);
System.out.println(sb.toString());

Color c = Color.CYAN;
int rgbValue = (c.getRed() << 16) + (c.getGreen() << 8) + c.getBlue();
String s = Integer.toHexString(rgbValue & 0xFFFFFF).toUpperCase();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 6 - s.length(); i++) {
    sb.append("0");
}
sb.append(s);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: As mentioned above, i get an error when i try to only use .getValue()

Comment: Is it normal that i cant find getRGB? all i can see is getRed(), get Blue() and getGreen()

Comment: According to Java API doc, .getRGB() is there since JDK1.0 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB()).

Answer (score 0):

use try catch function to handle it. if error hexa

Comment: This is not an answer. You **should write comment** under question.